# Customise rendering of individual series with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'd like to use a different `LineAndShapeRenderer` for each series on a JFreeChart `TimeSeries` graph. Has anyone accomplished this before? It seems the `Renderer` is owned by the `Plot` where each `JFreeChart` has a single `Plot` object hence the rendering is applicable to all series rather than individual ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried a case like that. However, I have changed the rendering properties of an specific `Series` with:

```
// chart is a JFreeChart object
XYItemRenderer renderer = chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesStroke(index, new BasicStroke(DEFAULT_LINE_WIDTH));
                        renderer.setSeriesPaint(/* index of series */, /*some color*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much, there is a similar method for the shape of a series:

```
XYItemRenderer renderer = chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesShape(int series, java.awt.Shape shape)
```